# How to get muilty Address sendbox sms android

Tags: android

I'm developing an application SMS. I'm fetch conversation by uri: "content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true".
I try get muilty address in sentbox,
[image]

I try get address by uri "content://mms-sms/canonical-address/" + recipientId", but it return 1 value

```
private String getAddress(int recipientId) {
    String[] projection = new String[]{"_id", "address" };
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/canonical-address/" + recipientId), projection, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cur);
    String address = "";
    while (cur.moveToNext())
    {
        address += cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"))+",";

    }
    return address;
}
```

Help me.
P.S. Sorry for my english, I'm VietNam. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem
Get address mms-sms by method

```
private String getAddress(String recipientId) {
        String address = "";
        String[] recipient = recipientId.split(" ");
        String[] projection = new String[]{"_id", "address" };
        int count = 0;
        for (String s: recipient) {
            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/canonical-address/" + s), projection, null, null, null);

            if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
                address += cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
                address+=",";
                cur.close();
            }
            count++;
        }
        return address;
    }
```